# How to replace an associated collection during ActiveRecord update in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-api

I have the following model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end
```

and I want to completely replace current `oder_items` during update instead of adding another one.

```
Order.update(
  order.id,
  order_items_attributes: order_items_attributes
)
```

but this adds new objects to `order_items` instead of replacing them. How to do that?

`order_items_attributes` are for example:

```
[{"category_id"=>"6e54977c-39e4-402e-93a0-f7a00952ebab", "quantity"=>1}]
```

Comment: first remove all older order_items "order.order_items.delete_all" and then add new ones.

Comment: could you please post the form?

Comment: and the inside of order_items

Comment: @SachinR, seems to be hacky ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the hash should look like:

```
Order.update(
  order.id,
  order_items_attributes: {id: 1, category_id: 123, quantity: 123 }
)
```

Comment: `order_items` requires `OrderItem` object, I pass a hash.